# Using prefetch_related on specific attributes?

Tags: python, sql, django, foreign-keys

I have the following code:

```
pictures_of_model: Model3D.objects.prefetch_related('Pictures')
```

Pictures is another table in which I store id's for pictures, the pictures themselves in an ImageField and an modelid that is a foreign key. How do I make sure that django prefetches the attribute with the ImageField and not the id of the picture?

```
pictures_of_model: Model3D.objects.prefetch_related('Pictures').picture
```

that can't be correct, right? Picture is my ImageField that holds, well, the picture.

I appreciate every answer that helps me learn, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

```
# You need to import Prefetch

from django.db.models import Prefetch

# Your query should be like this

Model3D.objects.prefetch_related(Prefetch('pictures', queryset=Pictures.objects.only('picture').all())).all()


# Where models could be

Class Pictures(models.Model):
    picture = ...

Class Model3D(models.Model):
    pictures = ..
```